# Receptacles in Kitchen Cabinets

Tags: electrical, cabinets

I am roughing in some plugs in my kitchen for when the workers come and hang the cabinets. I am getting cabinets with LV lights on the underside of them. The cabinet makers asked me to make sure I have my boxes out 5/8" past the drywall.

I am just wondering how I should go about this, since I am not sure how the workers hang the cabinets over top of my electrical boxes. Sticking the boxes out past my wood frame (5/8" + 1/2" for drywall) is quite far past the wood frame. Meaning I wouldn't be able to secure the box very well since the mounting holes for the box only go back about half the boxes depth.

I am using BX on wood frame (half the kitchen is steel studs and half is wood so I must use BX because some wires go between the steel studs and wood).

I can see two options. Perhaps there are better ones. My preferred method would be to use a 4x4 metal box, with a 1/2" mud ring. I understand how the drywallers go around a mud ring with a router, and it works great for them. Than I was wanted to wait till the cabinets were mounted and add a box extension for the 5/8". I am just unsure how the cabinet team will cut out my electrical box. Do they use a router? Or do they notch it out with a jigsaw based off where they measure it will be in there cabinet? I just don't want to leave them a rounded mud ring if they actually just need a squared off electrical box....

I could also get 1 1/8" mud rings I believe but they would be special order so I prefer not to.

Therefore the big question is, How do they cut out electrical outlets when hanging cabinets?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the cabinet installers, and asking them what they prefer?

Comment: Yes a few times, If it's not vacations, he is not in the office. I am ready to start my vacation, been waiting on this reply a few days...

Answer (score 2):

#### You do not need to move your electrical boxes out.

Just use these plastic extension fillers.

[image]

You might want to remove the receptacles as they can get stuck behind the cabinets if the "ears" on the receptacles are not removed.

Ears are the thin pieces of removable metal tabs on the top and bottom of the receptacle.  They have cut lines on them and can be removed using a pair of needle nose pliers.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method for prepping electrical boxes that will be in cabinets is to leave the wire hanging out of the wall, finish drywall, hang cabinets then use a remodel box secured to the installed cabinet.  This insures the box will be where I need it; in the cabinet and flush with the  back.
I use a Fein multi tool for cutting the back of the cabinets.
Most cabinet installers will not mount the electrical boxes and quite often are very sloppy in cutting out for existing electrical boxes.
I instruct the installers to use a 3/4" hole for the wire with enough room for the outlet plate - and I do the rest.